# How to change text color of text input boxes?

Tags: phpstorm

The text color of text fields in my PhpStorm is light grey and the background is white.

How to change the color?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change whole GUI Theme to a dark one.

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance & Behaviour | Appearance | Theme**

Use **"Darcula"** theme (instead of your current "IntelliJ") -- it's the only one that uses dark colors.